# How to get the last Textbox value before i hitting Delete key?

Tags: gwt

```
        itemBox.addKeyUpHandler( new KeyUpHandler()
        {
            public void onKeyUp( KeyUpEvent event )
            {
                String currentValue = itemBox.getValue().trim();
                // handle backspace
                if( event.getNativeKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_BACKSPACE )
                {
                    if( "".equals( currentValue ) )
                    {
                        doTheJob( );
                    }
                }
            }
        } );
```

Expect behavior:
when the textbox is empty, then i hit delete, will run doTheJob();

Current behavior:
when there is one character, i hit delete, it will trigger doTheJob();

In other word, is there any way i can get textbox content before i hit delete key?
I tried to used a var to hold the last value, but it needs to register another listener and the impl is not so effective.

Thanks for your input.

////////////////////Edit //////////////////////

use KeyDownHandler did solve the above problem, however lead to another problem:
i use itemBox.setValue( "" ); to clear the textbox but it will always have a comma there.

```
        itemBox.addKeyDownHandler( new KeyDownHandler()
        {
            public void onKeyDown( KeyDownEvent event )
            {
                // handle backspace
                if( event.getNativeKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_BACKSPACE )
                {
                    String currentValue = itemBox.getValue().trim();
                    if( "".equals( currentValue ) )
                    {
                       doTheJob();
                    }
                }
                // handle comma
                else if( event.getNativeKeyCode() == 188 )
                {
                     doOtherJob();
                    //clear TextBox for new input
                     itemBox.setValue( "" );
                     itemBox.setFocus( setFocus );
                }
            }
        } );
```

Comment: did you tried with the `onKeyDown` event?

Comment: What do you mean you hit delete? Is that a button? Because you are setting a key up handler to the text box, which will "doTheJob()"...If the hit delete is a button action, then remove the handler from the text box and add it to the button, onClickHandler() and check if the textbox is empty or not. textBox.isEmpty().

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, Delete is "Del" keyboard key which i already stated in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after

```
itemBox.setFocus( setFocus );
```

prevent event bubbling with

```
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
```

So the event will be canceled before comma is added to the textbox content.